# Is there a way to run a Google App engine cron task without hitting an endpoint but rather pointing cron.yaml at a python script?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

my end goal is to update Google cloud storage with some json data and I would rather it run a script rather than hitting a url endpoint. What would be the proper configuration of cron.yaml if, let's say the script were to sit right next to app.yaml?

Answer (score 2):

A cron job in GAE has to hit a URL, there's no other way to do it. That's just how the system is designed.

But since you have control over app.yaml anyway, you can easily assign your script to a URL there.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron):

> You cannot call a Google Cloud Endpoint from a cron job. Instead, you
>   should issue a request to a target that is served by a handler that's
>   specified in your app's configuration file or in a dispatch file. That
>   handler then calls the appropriate endpoint class and method.

However (from the same documentation),

> A cron job will invoke a URL, using an HTTP GET request, at a given
>   time of day. An HTTP request invoked by cron can run for up to 10
>   minutes, but is subject to the same limits as other HTTP requests.

If you set up the Routing in `main.py` to use a script right next to it and app.yaml, it would be called.  If that's what you call an endpoint, then that's what gets called.